# Number of subarrays whose mean rounds to zero

Tags: arrays, algorithm, mean

You have an array of integers. you have to find the number of subarrays which mean (sum of those elements divided by the count of those elements) rounds to zero.
I have solved this with O(n^2) time but it is not efficient enough. Is there a way to do it?

```
example:

[-1, 1, 5, 4]
subarrays which mean rounds to zero are: 
   [-1, 1] = 0 , [-1, 1, 5, -4] = 1/4 which rounds to zero
```

Answer (score 2):

Denote new array composed of pairs (prefix sum, cnt) where first element is the prefix summation and second element is number of elements, for example,

```
int[] arr = [-1, 1, 5 ,4]:
int[] narr = [(0, 0), (-1, 1), (0, 2), (5, 3), (9, 4)]
```

the question is converted to count pair `(i, j)` in `narr` where `i < j` and `Math.abs(narr[j][0] - narr[i][0]) < narr[j][1] - narr[i][1] = j - i` which is further boiled down to:

```
narr[j][0] - j < narr[i][0] - i < narr[i][0] + i < narr[j][0] + j
```

so the question is further converted to the following question:

for some intervals: [[1, 2], [-1, 0], ...] (initially is empty), given an interval [x, y], count how many intervals are totally within the range of [x, y], then we add this interval, and repeat this procedure for total N times. (how to manage the data structure of intervals become the key problem)

If we just brute force iterate every intervals and do the validation, the query time complexity is O(N) and insertion time complexity is O(1), total O(N^2)

If we use square decomposition, the query time complexity is O(sqrt(N)) and insertion time complexity is O(1) , total O(Nsqrt(N))

<del>If we use treap (using first or second as priority, use another as key), the average total time complexity we can achieve is O(NlgN)</del>

If you don't know the technique of square decomposition  <del>or treap</del> , I suggest you reading couple of articles first.

**Update:**

After carefully 30 mins thinking, I find treap cannot achieve O(NlgN) average time complexity.
Instead we can use **2d segment tree** to achieve O(NlgNlgN):
Please read this article instead:
[2d segment tree](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/segment_tree.html#toc-tgt-11)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Is it possible that you could help me with the code using the treap method? I don't quite know how to implement that